# Strong weak symbol -> double to char array

Tags: c, pointers, types, linker, symbols

I am trying to learn more about linking, more specifically how strong symbols override weak symbols if they have the same name. I saw an example but there was no answer and I have been really stuck on it.

file1.c

```
char a[5];

int main() { printf("%s", a); }
```

file2.c

```
double a = ???????;
```

how can I set a in file2.c so that the linker interprets it as a char array and outputs "hello" when these two files are compiled and executed?

Comment: `char[5] a;` is not valid C syntax. And what you seem to try invokes undefined behaviour. What do you **actually** want to accomplish? What is the reason you want to do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Adding a link to the example that you saw may help. Note that although strong and weak symbols may be a linker feature (potentially useful for assembly code), there is no such concept in C. So you need to explain what you expect that feature to do.

Answer (score 1):

As  @user3386109 noted, there are is no concept of `strong` v. `weak` symbols
in Standard C. Some compilers support these concepts via non-Standard,
non-portable, language extensions.

GCC, for example, supports weak symbols with the
[non-standard declaration syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

```
__attribute__((weak)) <normal_declaration>
```

or alternatively the [preprocessor pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Weak-Pragmas.html#Weak-Pragmas):

```
#pragma weak <symbol>
```

For GCC, an example such as you want would be:

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[] = "Hello World";

extern double b;

int main(void) 
{ 
    printf("%s %f\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
__attribute__((weak)) double a = 1.1;
double b = 2.2;
```

Compile and link:

```
$ gcc -o prog file1.c file2.c
```

Run:

```
$ ./prog
Hello World 2.200000
```

If you delete `__attribute__((weak))` and rebuild, there will be a 
multiple-definition linkage error.

Microsoft compilers only "sort of" support weak symbol declarations via
[`__declspec(selectany)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tkz6s71.aspx)

In realistic applications there are linkage gotchas with the use of weak symbols,
whereby a weak symbol definition may be linked even when a strong definition is also available. Compilers (including Microsoft's) generate weak symbols
under the hood, for instance to cope with the linkage of public inline functions.
They do so in a highly regulated and expert way. Once you understand weak symbols, do your best to avoid them.